# Invalid KeyConditionExpression: Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator or function: begins_with

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am trying to learn single table design in DynamoDB with direct lambda resolvers. This is my DynamoDB table: [image: DynamoDB table] I am trying to query all the users by company ID. But I am getting the error in my cloudwatch: *Invalid KeyConditionExpression: Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator or function: begins_with*. But in the query document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html there is a begins_with in KeyConditionExpression.

This is my lambda function's index.js

```
const getUsersByCompanyId = require('./getUsersByCompanyId')

exports.handler = async(event) => {
    const { arguments, info: { fieldName } } = event
    
    switch (fieldName) {
        case 'getUsersByCompanyId':
            const data =  await getUsersByCompanyId(arguments.companyId)
            console.log(data)
        default:
           return null
    }
    
};
```

This is my lambda function's getUsersByCompanyId.js

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()

async function getUsersByCompanyId(companyId){
    const params = {
        TableName: "CompanyA",
        KeyConditionExpression: `PK = :companyId AND begins_with ( SK, :sk )`,
        ExpressionAttributeValues:{
            ':companyId' : companyId,
            ':sk': {"S": "USER#"}
        }
    }
    try{
        const data = await docClient.query(params).promise() 
        return data
    }catch(err){
        return err
    }
}

module.exports = getUsersByCompanyId
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed my getUsersByCompanyId.js to:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()

async function getUsersByCompanyId(companyId){
    const params = {
        TableName: "CompanyA",
        KeyConditionExpression: `PK = :companyId and begins_with(SK, :sk)`,
        ExpressionAttributeValues:{
            ':companyId' : companyId,
            ':sk': "USER#"
        }
    }
    try{
        const data = await docClient.query(params).promise() 
        return data
    }catch(err){
        return err
    }
}

module.exports = getUsersByCompanyId
```

and it works. I wish there were more tutorials on Direct Lambda resolvers, I found this tutorial to be somewhat helpful,
https://www.twitch.tv/videos/731600097 , here is the resource for that tutorial https://gist.github.com/dabit3/96dc51e688b18a7d40fc534331758c56